# @WebServlet mapping error on Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, glassfish

I'm getting the following SEVERE error on Glassfish 3.1 upon startup :

> The servlet 'MyInheritingServlet' has implementation
>   'com.mycompany.MyInheritingServlet' in xml. It does
>   not match with 'com.mycompany.MyBaseServlet'
>   from annotation @WebServlet.

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
  @WebServlet(name = "MyInheritingServlet", urlPatterns = "/MyInheritingServlet")
    public class MyInheritingServlet extends MyBaseServlet {
// implementation & overrides here ....
}

    @WebServlet(name = "MyBaseServlet", urlPatterns = "/MyBaseServlet")
    public class MyBaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
// implementation & overrides here ....
}
```

Can anyone explain why Glassfish is emitting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `MyInheritingServlet` is extending `MyBaseServlet`.

Because `MyInheritingServlet` inherits everything, it also inherits the `@WebServlet` annotation from `MyBaseServlet`. So it looks similar to that:

```
  @WebServlet(name = "MyInheritingServlet", urlPatterns = "/MyInheritingServlet")
  @WebServlet(name = "MyBaseServlet", urlPatterns = "/MyBaseServlet")
  public class MyInheritingServlet extends MyBaseServlet {
  // implementation & overrides here ....
  }
```

This seems to confuse the implementation in Glassfish 3.1. But it seems to work without an error message in Glassfish 4.1.

From [The Java EE 6 Tutorial - Chapter 10 Java Servlet Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnafd/index.html):

> Classes annotated with @WebServlet must extend the
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet class.

Comment: Thanks @unwichtich. I still don't quite understand why MyInheritingServlet inherits the `@WebServlet` annotation from its base. Shouldn't the `@WebServlet` annotation have the `@Inherited` annotation in order to be inherited by subclasses?     AFAIK, `@WebServlet` is not inherited to subclasses: [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html)